# Reload UITableView data and not the visible cells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I'm working on an app where I want to pull data from a remote web service and populate a UITableView. When I get new data I want the currently visible cells to remain and add the new data above it, much like most Twitter clients does. My load method currently looks like this:

```
- (void)loadPostsInBackground
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[URL]"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation;
    operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject) {

        [self createPostsFromDict:jsonObject];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id jsonObject) {

        NSLog(@"Received an HTTP %d", response.statusCode);
        NSLog(@"The error was: %@", error);

    }];

    [operation start];

}
```

This works, but it updates the currently visible cells with the new data. So what I want is, get new data, add it above the currently visible cells (or stay at the currently visible cells). What is the best way to do this?

Note: I will require iOS6.

Comment: Are you still usin the fetchedResultsController? I'm not sure that will work to do what you want. Does createPostsFromDict retune an array that you can populate your table with?

Comment: Yes, still using it. Kind of got it to work by adding the number of new posts to an instance variable, and then scrolling to that row without an animation after the new rows have been loaded. But it's not perfect or pretty, but it works. createPostsFromDict dosn't return an array, it just adds posts to my managedObjectContext.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling **reloadData** on the table view. You should call **insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:**. Do that after updating the data used by the table view's data source.

Comment: Thanks, I use an NSFetchResultController in both numberOfSections and numberOfRows, I'm not completely sure how I should update that properly. I have tried with `NSError *error [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];` before `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`, but it didn't work. Keep getting: `Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0...`

Comment: What you were doing before to update the data model should work. The only change you really need is how you updated the table. When you call the **insertRows...** method, all of the data source methods will be called. As long as they return the correct numbers you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, I removed `reloadData` and changed it to `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]; NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]; [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];`, but I get the same error.

Comment: That code assumes you are only adding 1 row. It that correct? If your data source has been update with 0 rows or more than 1 row then you will get that error. I'm not familiar how you are updating your data structures but they need to be updated with the same amount of rows that you are trying to insert.

Comment: Ok, I see, no it could be multiple rows. Not very familiar with insertRowsAtIndexPaths. So, is it possible to make it more dynamic, because I don't know how many rows it will be.

Comment: The call to **insertRows...** requires that you provide one index path for each row you need to insert. Can't you determine the count from the jsonObject you get in the callback? One other thing. The indexPaths you insert should truly represent the index paths of the new rows. If the new rows are scattered about the table then using reloadData is probably the better choice. But if you are really just adding N rows at the top then add N indexPaths with the proper rows in the call to **insertRows...**

Comment: It is showing that new cells are adding and I want to current visible cell should show not new added cell. New added cell will show when user scroll

Comment: @AdityaSharma If you have a question, please post a new question with all relevant details.